# Copied iPhone storyboard and pasted directly into iPad storyboard, but not every view controller displays correctly on iPad

Tags: swift, xcode

I am making separate storyboards for my app on iPhone and iPad. All of the elements on both storyboards are the same, but I needed to change a few things like font size, constraints, etc.

I did Command A (select all) and Command C to copy all of the iPhone view controllers. Then I did Command V to paste all the VCs into the iPad storyboard. Most of the VCs in the iPad storyboard display with the correct iPad format, but a few of the VCs will still display with the iPhone format even when I'm using an iPad...

I made sure that the iPad storyboard was being used for the iPad device type. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Do the views have constraints? If not, you probably need to add appropriate constraints.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I have different constraints for the iPad and iPhone storyboards. But when I run the app on an iPad a few of the view controller appear with the iPhone constraints

Comment: instead this copy sotryboard rename it and then select sotryboard  in bottom you will see devices   trait variation select ipad device and your ipad storyboard is ready.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I tried copying my edited iPad storyboard and renaming it, but the same iPad view controllers are still displaying in the iPhone format... Some iPad view controllers are displaying correctly and others are not, which is weird

Comment: select that controller and go to attribute inspector change simulated matrics, size to inferred.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan It is already set to inferred